# Show $\operatorname{div}(\nabla u^T) = \nabla \operatorname{div}(u)$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a vector valued function $u: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Assume that $u$ is twice differentiable and all of the second-order partial derivatives of $u$ are continuous. Use components to establish the following identities:

(a) $\operatorname{div}(\nabla u^T) = \nabla \operatorname{div}(u)$

(b) $\operatorname{div}[(\nabla u)u] - \operatorname{div}(u)u = \nabla u^T \cdot \nabla u - (\operatorname{div}u)^2$

I have no idea how to go about this problem. Could someone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: You shouldn't keep oscillating in and out of MathJax in the course of a long expression in mathematical notation.  Just stay in MathJax until you come to something that's not mathematical notation.  I edited your question accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: The calculation might depend on notations used by your textbook. Anyway, (a) is a straight forward calculation to check. (b) might need Einstein notation for the convenience of calculation.

Comment: As hinted: use the components of $u$. have you tried it in $\mathbb R^3$?